# OpenCV c++ Mat MADNESS

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, matrix

So i have a object with three global Mat (bear with me), I wish to fill with doubles, I also have a print method

so in **Main.hpp**

```
Main class {
...
Mat FIXED;
Mat one;
Mat two;
...
}
```

and in my **Main.cpp** i have

```
void Main::printMat( Mat mat ) {
    int rows = mat.rows;
    int cols = mat.cols;
    for (int j = 0, j < cols; j++ ) { 
        for (int i = 0, i < rows; i++ ) { 
            printf( "%lf ", mat.at<double>(i,j)); 
        } 
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

So for any matrix input it everything stores fine.

```
printMat(one); <--this works
```

**THIS WORKS FINE**, but then i do

```
two = FIXED.clone();
```

**THEN THIS BREAKS, I HAVE NO IDEA WHY HELP**

```
printMat(one); <--this doesnt work
```

If i comment out the .clone() line it works, if i make a blank matrix of same size and save to FIXED it doesnt work.

Comment: All matrices are of type `CV_64FC1`? If not this will likely break. shouldn't you call `printMat` from an instance of class Main? BTW, you can simply use `cout << mat << endl;` for printing matrices

Comment: Think it defaults to 1 Channel not sure. Anyways it was my mistake i wrote up an answer. Guess rookie error referenc vs value error, but easily confusing.

Comment: I don't understand why you transpose the matrix while printing (your code prints the values of each column in a row, then newline and go to the next row), nor why you aren't using `cout`, but you can accomplish the same task with something more readable (IMHO): `for (int j = 0, j < cols; j++ ) { for (int i = 0, i < rows; i++ ) { printf( "%lf ", mat.at<double>(i,j)); } printf("\n"); }`

Comment: Ooops apologies, have edited =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this,the reason was how i was creating the one array.

So i made a print method initially because

```
cout << someMat << endl;
```

was giving me weird numbers

turns out thats the fault right there, it should give me normal values that i stored in.

I was making the Mat inside a method by passing in a Array[row][col] using

```
void foo() {
    one = Mat(Array.rows, Array.cols, CV_64F, Array);
}

void bar() {
 printMat(one)//error happens here
}

main (...) {
    foo();
    bar();
}
```

Turns out the constructor uses the **reference** of the Array and **NOT** the value and so when i leave the method i lose that bit of memory to the Garbage collector.

The fact it was breaking after the line i mentioned was mere coincidence. (Since that was in a different method and this point the GC decided to clear up)

Comment: There's no garbage collector in C++ ;D

Comment: ahaha feel free to fix, this c++ stuff is so out of my league

Comment: I can't. I don't even understand where the issue was, since you didn't show all the relevant code. I guess you can just delete the question since you find a fix, but there's no info on how other may benefit from this.

Comment: The problem was the Arrays referenced when creating Mats, the values arent copied into the Mat. I didnt know how to word it properly, feel free to comment a better wording and ill edit it later.